# Loading .so files crashed on some android devices

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

When i am trying to load my .SO files from libs by using the `System.loadLibrary("myfile")` i am getting the following exception.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
Couldn't load stlport_shared from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader
[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.package.name-2.apk"],
nativeLibraryDirectories=
[/data/app-lib/com.package.name-2, /system/lib]]]: 
findLibrary returned null
```

I am getting this exception on some devices only. please help me.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21970007/inexplicable-unsatisfiedlinkerror-on-native-library-load

Comment: Also see here: https://medium.com/keepsafe-engineering/the-perils-of-loading-native-libraries-on-android-befa49dce2db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the Libs folder create the following folders armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86, mips then copy the .So file into the respective folders. clean the project then run.

These folders under the libs (armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86, mips) are selected at runtime depends on the processors.