# "Unrecognized option 'filter_complex'" error when using FFmpeg in Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I am creating a watermark application using FFmpeg in Android.
I used the following command

```
ffmpeg -i /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/VID-20150217-WA0002.mp4 -i /storage/emulated/0/mp4parser/img001.png -filter_complex '[0:v][1:v]overlay[out]'  -map '[out]' /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/trimmed-038-VID-20150217-WA0002.mp4
```

When I launched the app, I got this line in the log:

```
Unrecognized option 'filter_complex'
```

I have read this command on the FFmpeg.org site, but I don't know why it is not working. Below is the log:

```
02-27 16:14:55.881: E/VideoTrimmer(13315): Starting to watermark
02-27 16:14:55.881: E/VideoTrimmer(13315): ffmpeg
02-27 16:14:55.881: E/VideoTrimmer(13315): -i
02-27 16:14:55.881: E/VideoTrimmer(13315): /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/VID-20150217-WA0002.mp4
02-27 16:14:55.881: E/VideoTrimmer(13315): -i
02-27 16:14:55.882: E/VideoTrimmer(13315): /storage/emulated/0/mp4parser/img001.png
02-27 16:14:55.882: E/VideoTrimmer(13315): -filter_complex
02-27 16:14:55.882: E/VideoTrimmer(13315): '[0:v][1:v]overlay[out]'
02-27 16:14:55.882: E/VideoTrimmer(13315): -map
02-27 16:14:55.882: E/VideoTrimmer(13315): '[out]'
02-27 16:14:55.883: E/VideoTrimmer(13315): /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/trimmed-038-VID-20150217-WA0002.mp4
02-27 16:14:55.883: E/VideoTrimmer(13315): Printed all
02-27 16:14:55.944: E/TakePics(13315): FFmpeg version 0.6.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
02-27 16:14:55.944: E/TakePics(13315):   built on Feb 27 2015 16:12:28 with gcc 4.8
02-27 16:14:55.944: E/TakePics(13315):   configuration: --target-os=linux --arch=arm --enable-version3 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --disable-stripping --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --disable-ffprobe --disable-devices --disable-protocols --enable-protocol=file --enable-avfilter --disable-network --disable-mpegaudio-hp --disable-avdevice --enable-cross-compile --cc=/home/uday/mount/android-ndk-r4b/build/prebuilt/linux-x86/arm-eabi-4.4.0/bin/arm-eabi-gcc --cross-prefix=/home/uday/mount/android-ndk-r4b/build/prebuilt/linux-x86/arm-eabi-4.4.0/bin/arm-eabi- --nm=/home/uday/mount/android-ndk-r4b/build/prebuilt/linux-x86/arm-eabi-4.4.0/bin/arm-eabi-nm --extra-cflags='-fPIC -DANDROID' --disable-asm --enable-neon --enable-armv5te --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-T,/home/uday/mount/android-ndk-r4b/build/prebuilt/linux-x86/arm-eabi-4.4.0/arm-eabi/lib/ldscripts/armelf.x -Wl,-rpath-link=/home/uday/mount/android-ndk-r4b/build/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib -L/home/uday/mount/android-ndk-r4b/build/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib -nostdli
02-27 16:14:56.152: E/TakePics(13315): Unrecognized option 'filter_complex'
```

I have also tried using filter:v.

Comment: Without looking into the source code, it is tempting to wonder if this is something you have to enable with a configuration option when building FFMPEG.

Comment: single quote or double? try both...  http://betterlogic.com/roger/2012/08/ffmpeg-scale-with-overlay-filter_complex/