# UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__aeabi_memcpy4" referenced by

Tags: android, android-ndk

I've just updated from NDK 12.x to 13.x and now I'm getting the following crash:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__aeabi_memcpy4" referenced by "/data/app/com.app.myapp-1/lib/arm/libJniBitmapOperationsLibrary.so"...
  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:372)
  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
  at com.jni.bitmap_operations.JniBitmapHolder.<clinit>(JniBitmapHolder.java:11)
  <...>
```

The library I'm using is available [here](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AndroidJniBitmapOperations).

I've seen a few similar issues on SO to do with `cannot locate symbol` and all the suggestions were around setting `APP_PLATFORM` in the `Application.mk` file. My JNI library is part of the SDK so I don't have `Application.mk` file - only `Android.mk`. Also my target/min sdk didn't change recently. My `Android.mk` file is copied from the library and looks like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

#bitmap operations module
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := JniBitmapOperationsLibrary
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := JniBitmapOperationsLibrary.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -ljnigraphics

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
APP_OPTIM := debug
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -g
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I've figured out an answer with the help of [JNI and Gradle in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096819/jni-and-gradle-in-android-studio) and [Android NDK : Getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "signal" referenced by "libffmpeg.so"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28740315/android-ndk-getting-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-dlopen-failed-cannot-loca?rq=1)

The solution for me was to do the following:

1) add `Application.mk` file with the following:

```
APP_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)  
APP_ABI := all  
APP_PLATFORM := android-19
```

2) update my `build.gradle` to point at my `Application.mk` as apparently gradle creates its own version of `Android.mk` and defaults to the same api level as you have in `compileSdkVersion` not `minSdkVersion`.

With `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0` this can be achieved by adding the following (for more details check out the JNI SO post mentioned above):

```
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path 'src/main/jni/Application.mk'
    }
}
```

Also, you probably don't need both steps one and two, but I've spent too much time on this already to verify