# UnsatisfiedLinkError native method not found - Android-Telegram

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, telegram

I downloaded Telegram Source code from GitHub and Compile it. at first, it gave me some error about `NDK_PROJECT_PATH = null` and so as someone suggested i changed :

```
    sourceSets.main.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['./jni/']
    externalNativeBuild {        
    ndkBuild {
        path "jni/Android.mk"
       }
    }
```

to :

```
sourceSets.main {
    jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
    jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
}
```

in gradle.
after run 2 .so file generated in `libs\armeabi` and `libs\armeabi-v7a` (both of them about 4kb) and i can get the **LaunchActivity.java**  , but when i click on **START MESSAGING** the app crashes at `ApplicationLoader.loadWallpaper();` (in LaunchActivity.java) which runs a runnable. i debbuged it until i reached to `uncaughtException` which was as following :
**unsatisfiedlinkerror native method not found: org.telegram.messenger.Utilities.pinBitmap: (Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;)**

after that i again compile native jni Manualy from command prompt (i mean going to nji parent folder and run ndk-build.cmd) .
when compilation finished  "obj" folder was created in nji parent folder and that 2 files generated again but with size of 14kb.
I replace them with old ones in the libs folder.

after Clean and Rerun, i still have same error (native method not found...).

can any body help me what's wrong with this NDK ??
any help would be appreciated.
Thanks, MA.

Comment: Have you downloaded the NDK and pointed studio at it ?

Comment: @Jon Goodwin ,of course , it's in C:\Users\Mohamad\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle and I set it in Project structure

Comment: Have you checked your `TARGET_PLATFORM`/`APP_PLATFORM`? It should match your minSdkVersion. Had a similar issue yesterday - this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468805/unsatisfiedlinkerror-dlopen-failed-cannot-locate-symbol-aeabi-memcpy4-refe

Answer (score 0):

all the problem was because of the directory of my project.
the directory contains space and it's not compatible with NDK.
I moved the project to another directory and now it compiles.