# Android Studio/Gradle is not packing my shared library named "mylib.so.1" in APK

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk

I need to pack a shared library named "mylib.so.1" into APK,but apparently gradle does not recognize ".so.1" extension, only ".so" and at runtime I need the library named ".so.1" to avoid linker errors. All libs are in src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the suffix be exactly **.so**. So remove the redundant **.1**

Comment: If I do this, at runtime I get a linker error, "mylib.so.1 missing" in logcat.

Comment: You need to remove the suffix *and* relink anything that was linked against it. Removing the suffix post build is not sufficient. Also check that the SONAME of the library is correct (follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/48291044/632035).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to package versioned .so files by adding them as resources via

```
sourceSets.main {
    resources.srcDir 'src/main/external'
}
```

inside the `android` block in `app.gradle`. Alternatively one could use `resources.srcDirs += ['src/main/whatever']`.

This copies all files at the specified path to the root of the package, so the source libraries would have to be placed at `src/main/external/lib/armeabi-v7a/libsomething.so.1.2.3` etc. in order to be copied to `/lib/armeabi-v7a/libsomething.so.1.2.3` in the `.apk` or `.aar`.

Except, somewhat ironically, it doesn't seem to copy files which are presumed to be libraries (i.e. files matching *.so and possibly others). So you'll have to put your .so's in `src/jniLibs`.