# Include native .so library with specific version into Android .aar archive

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, shared-libraries

It seems to me that gradle Android plugin does not include versioned .so libraries into .aar archive.

My case:
I need to load some library in Android application that requires another library: `libz.so.1`

I do have `libz.so` and `libz.so.1` in my native libraries directory.

After running gradle there is only `libz.so` library in created .aar archive.
It results in `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libz.so.1" not found` exception when I try to run my application.

It looks like my `otherlibrary` tries to load only that specific version of libz.

`readelf -d otherlibrary.so` also tells me that it wants specific library:
`0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libz.so.1]`

Both libraries that I want to load are third party libraries.
It looks like I need to find a way for one of the following:

- pack `libz.so.1` into .aar archive, so `otherlibrary.so` could easily link with it
- load `libz.so` and somehow make `otherlibrary.so` to link with it

but I'm running out of ideas, how to do it.

Part of build.gradle that builds .aar archive:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }
}
```

`libs` directory contains both `libz.so` and `libs.so.1` libraries. Only `libz.so` is assembled into .aar file.

This page: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#aar-contents
suggests me that only `/jni/abi_name/name.so` pattern is supported.

Looking forward for some help.

Comment: If your `otherlibrary.so` was originally compiled using Android NDK, i don't think it should have the reference like `xxx.so.1`. Hence, probably you need to have a proper `otherlibrary.so` first.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53137079/8034839

Comment: So the only solution was to rebuild zlib, so its SONAME would be libz.so, not libz.so.1

Thank you.