# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/Users/..." not found

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I want to add another lib into [android-ndk hello-libs](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/issues/364) example.

In `CMakeLists.txt`, I add:

```
# this is from the hello-libs sample code
add_library(lib_gperf SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lib_gperf PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${distribution_DIR}/gperf/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/libgperf.so)

########## I add this after the sample code:  ###########
add_library(lib_py SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lib_py PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${distribution_DIR}/gperf/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/libpython.so)
```

And this:

```
target_link_libraries(
        hello-libs
        android
        lib_gperf

        #### this line ######
        lib_py

        log)
```

And copy `libpython.so` in the directory where `libgperf.so` located:

[image]

Also copy the python headers into the include directory:

[image]

When I click the run button:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/Users/finn/Downloads/hello-libs/app/src/main/cpp/../../../../distribution/gperf/lib/arm64-v8a/libpython.so" not found
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1016)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1657)
        at com.example.hellolibs.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:36)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1174)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2747)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2931)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1620)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6698)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782)
```

The path exists in my computer, but why the apk use my computer path, but not the android device path?

And I use the Android device file explorer, the lib is in the directory:

[image]

Then how can I make the apk use the right path?

Or I miss something to add?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android NDK: dlopen failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47279824/android-ndk-dlopen-failed)

Answer (score 1):

I encounter the exact same issue and I discovered that when the .so file is built, the library link for the python library is wrong  while the link for gperf library is ok.
[Link error for python library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPSK0.png)
Both libraries are imported with the exact same method in the cmake so it doesn't make sense.
I friend of mine told me it is a bug from ninja and they provided me a "turn-around" solution. You have to import the python library as if it was an Android-NDK provided one (like Android or Log).

The library should be put in the NDK libraries, which should be located at `<NDK PATH>/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/<OS_related_folder>/sysroot/usr/lib/<ABI targeted>/<minSdkVersion/`

Where:
- `NDK path` is the location of your NDK folder.
- `OS_related_folder` is the os_named folder (in my case windows-x86_64).
- `ABI` targeted is the ABI to which your library is compiled for (arm-linux-androideabi, aarch64-linux-android, etc).
- `minSdkVersion` is the number of your min SDK version of your project.
This information was found from `CMakeCache.txt`, in the folder `\app.cxx\cmake\debug\\'. When using find_library for log, the path of the library is shown

Change `CMakeLists.txt` to only provide library include, and directly link the library by it's name (python2.7 for libpython2.7.so)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library( native-lib SHARED native-lib.cpp)

include_directories( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../../libs/python/include/ )

find_library( log-lib log ) # Optional

target_link_libraries( native-lib python2.7 ${log-lib} )
```

Since the python library isn't natively provided by Android, you will need to pack it to the APK by changing the jnLibs folders (see [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds#jniLibs))

Following these steps should fix the issue
[Resulting library link in .so file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7qZu.png)

Obviously, this is not a good solution. I hope my answer will draw more attention on this issue and somebody will provide a real solution to avoid such tweaks

Comment: I have the same issue and cannot resolve by this approach. Is there any other solutions? Could the problem caused by the .so file itself?

Comment: I believe that the location where to put the .so isn't correct.
I used to put it in the "ndk-bundle/platforms/android-<build version>/<android abi>/usr/lib/" but with a recent update of android update, the location changed.
I do not compile the libpython through Android Studio anymore, so I cannot test it myself.
Could you try it and report the result?

Comment: I created a new projet and redo the whole process. The location where to put the file is <Android-SDK-Location>\<NDK-Bundle>\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\sysroot\usr\lib\<Android ABI>\<minSdkVersion>

If you are unsure of where to put the library, add log as requirement and check the CMakeCache.txt in the .cxx/cmake/debug/<ABI> folder
The path of the log library will be provided, this is where you should put your library

Comment: Thank you Paul for your complete explanation. I'll try and report the result.

Answer (score -1):

Assume path `/Users/finn/Downloads/hello-libs/app/src/main/cpp/../../../../distribution/gperf/lib` is correct, then you can configure your JNI libs like below:

```
sourceSets {
    release {
        jniLibs.srcDirs += ["/Users/finn/Downloads/hello-libs/app/src/main/cpp/../../../../distribution/gperf/lib"]
    }
    debug {
        jniLibs.srcDirs += ["/Users/finn/Downloads/hello-libs/app/src/main/cpp/../../../../distribution/gperf/lib"]
    }
}
```

Try to change `/Users/finn/Downloads/hello-libs/app/src/main/cpp/../../../../distribution/gperf/lib` if it is not your correct path to the jni libs.