# Using dlopen and a replacement function to load a native library without full path

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk

I currently use dlopen native function to open a native lib (so file).

```
handle = dlopen(libPath, RTLD_LAZY);
```

I use a full path to the library.
unfortunately with the new app bundle installation (abb file) there is no way to get the path to the lib.
Did someone found a workaround for this?

Thanks,
Eli

Answer (score 1):

`dlopen` using the `SONAME` of the library. `dlopen("libmylib.so", ...)` does not require an absolute path. If that doesn't work then your library is built incorrectly and should follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/48291044/632035 to fix it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked (at least for new devices).