# 'clear cache' from settings removes .so files in data directory

Tags: android, caching, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

My application is having native code so my data directory is having lib directory `/data/data/mypackage/lib/libxxx.so`

when I remove cache by `'clear cache'` button in settings after swipe kill from recent list, sometimes it **removes .so files** keeping lib directory. (it happens in LG k10 with Android 7.0). It works well on first use before clearing cache while lib folder is having libxxx.so.

I load my lib by following code.

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("xxx");
    }
```

after clearing cache and relaunch of application ,  it gives following error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/mypackage-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/mypackage-1/lib/arm, /system/fake-libs, /data/app/mypackage-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libxxx.so"
```

**The only option after this error is to reinstall the application as .so files are removed for unknown reason**.

What can I do in such case?

Note : `mypackage` is package name of my app and `libxxx.so` is native lib. Original names I am hiding for some reasons.

Comment: Where have you put this line of code? `System.loadLibrary("xxx");`

Comment: in my activity class. which is a single activity in my app

Comment: Check if this directory still has the libxxx.so file. `/data/app/mypackage/lib/`

Comment: my device is not rooted. so is there any way to check that directory ? I cannot open it through adb shell or ddms.

Comment: How did you check that files were removed from `/data/data/mypackage/lib/` directory?

Comment: You can test this on an emulator. You should be able to access these directories there.

Comment: on Emulator I am not getting this error. only in this LG device.

Comment: try using `run-as -your.app.package-` when in adb shell, i dont have debugable application with native libraries, but it seams to show libs also

Comment: yes I am using the same method but it's not allowing to go into /data/app directory

Comment: and it is not possible to `ls lib`?  `ls lib` gives me empty folder, where 'ls data/app-lib/package` gives me no such file error

Comment: `ls lib` after run-as gives empty directory and `ls data/app-lib/package` not working for me

Comment: I also have this problem, on android 7.1.1 emulator. When I clear data libs dir are empty

Comment: this working for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111739/why-do-some-android-phones-cause-our-app-to-throw-an-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinker

Comment: Thanx @Andrzej, you mean to say https://stackoverflow.com/a/24296556/1602333 this is working , right?